# In Indesign cs6, is there a way to link placed text that was generated using data merge?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, cs6, data-merge

I'm working on a catalog layout and have all product information is a csv file. I'm using data merge to import this into Indesign so that my paragraph and character styles stay intact.

Other people will be editing the csv file on a regular basis so ideally, I would like to link all of my text in Indesign to the csv file so the new information automatically shows up in my indd document. Is there a way to do this when using data merge fields?

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins, XCatalog by Em Software comes to mind, but that isn't an inexpensive solution.  However, it does babysit the process.  Does InCopy provide any options for you?